# How to print out an SSRS report for each customer on the customer dropdown list

Tags: reporting-services

We have an SSRS report which takes customerID as a parameter, and we would like to print out a report for each of the customers on the Customer dropdown list. However, there are a few hundreds of customers on the list, and we are not able to go through each one manually. Is there a way to have the report automatically go through the customer dropdown list and generate a report for each customer, so we can print out the report all at once on our end?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a few ways. As you already have a report that does a single customer then it will be easy to use this as a sub report.

Note that this, as with most options, will give you a single report containing everything, it will not give you actual individual reports..

So, Create a new report. Create a dataset (say `dsCustomers`) that contains a list of CustomerID's that you need to report from. This dataset could be a simple query such as `SELECT CustomerID FROM myCustomersTable` for exmaple.

Now add a table to your report and set it's dataset property to `dsCustomers`.

Remove the header row from the table as we don't need this and remove all but one column so you tablix is just a single textbox. Make this textbox wide (it's doesn't really matter how wide, it's just to make things easier to see)

Now in the remaining textbox, right-click and choose "Insert => Subreport"

Right-click the subreport placeholder and choose "properties"

Now set the subreport to your original report.

In the parameters section add a parameter entry for your subreport's parameter. Assuming the subreport takes a parameter called `CustID` then select `CustID` from the drop down. On hte right side, the parameter value, set this to the name of your `dsCustomers` dataset field (in this example it would be `CustomerID`)

That's it...

Now when you run the report, the tablix will produce 1 row per CustomerID,, each 'row' will contain the subreport.

You will probably want to set page breaks on the rowgroup too so each customer starts on a new page.